# Foreach loop for a string

Tags: algorithm2e

how do I write

```
foreach triple ti in Q  do  
Q <- M
```

in latex I have tried

```
\foreach \triple ti in {Q} {Q \gets M}
```

but it doesnt work
 I want the result to be  displayed as follow  it is a sort of an algorithm whriten in the report

".....
Foreach Triple pattern  ti ∈ Q Do

Q<- M " 
...

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
   {MFS} $(Q,D)$\;
    \Input{ A failing Query Q = t1$\wedge$t2$\wedge$...$\wedge$tn and RDF Database D ;}
    \Output{An MFS denoted by Q* ;}
    Q $\gets$ Q* ; \\
    Q' $\gets$ Q* ; \\


    \caption{Find An MFS in a failing SPARQL Query}



\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I want this result

[image]

Comment: your question is very unclear, what is `Q` here? which package are you using to define `\foreach` ?

Comment: is this a typesetting or a programming question ?

Comment: I'm not using any package , Q is q Query @DavidCarlisle

Comment: it is a typesetting quetion , I want to write an  pseudo code algorithm  using Latex    @jfbu

Comment: oh you want to _typeset it? I assumed you wanted to loop through something as latex code. You could just use `\begin{verbatim}`....or look at any of the `algorithm` packages. both of the tags you use are about tex programming, looping within tex. I retagged, have a look at any of the examples here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms

Comment: when I use verbatim foreach isnt written as a loop it is just written as  a text . If I want it to be pprogramed what do I type ?

Comment: @AndrewCashner I have edited the question check it out please

Comment: please make your example a small document that people can test so we don't have to guess which packages you have used to define `\SetKwInOut` the example should be complete `\documentclass...\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I edited the post

Comment: the code posted produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BBVTS.png) what exactly do you want to change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46134/discussion-between-muna-ar-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `\ForEach{<condition>}{<stuff>}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Find an \texttt{MFS} of a failing \texttt{SPARQL} query~$Q$}
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{inputs}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
  \SetKwProg{FindAnMFS}{FindAnMFS}{}{}

  \FindAnMFS{$(Q,D)$}{
    \Input{A failing query $Q = t_1 \wedge \dots \wedge t_n$; an \texttt{RDF} database $D$}
    \Output{An \texttt{MFS} denoted by $Q^*$}
    $Q^* \gets \emptyset$\;
    $Q' \gets Q$\;
    \ForEach{triple pattern $t_i \in Q$}{%
      $Q' \gets Q' - t_i$\;
      \If{$[[Q' \wedge Q^*]]_D \neq \emptyset$}{%
        $Q^* \gets Q^* \wedge t_i$\;
      }
    }
    \KwRet{$Q^*$}\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I've also defined a *program* called `\FindAnMFS` to obtain the outer block.