# Writing a pseudocode in latex for safety analytics. Hwne I write statement foreach it is giving me error undefined control sequence. please help me

Tags: algorithm2e

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\include{pythonlisting}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{{\bf Context-aware multi-stage health and safety surveillance} \label{Algorithm}}
\KwIn{Path of videos $V$, All stage detection models $\Omega$, stage detector $\phi_o$}
\BlankLine
Load the video ($v$)\;
\BlankLine
\foreach video(i) in videos:

    
\KwOut{List of detected objects $\Lambda_o$, Site occupancy matrix $\sigma_o$, Collision matrix $\mu_c$}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. You could write your question in the question instead of writing it only in the title.

Comment: Wrong capitalization. Roughly like this [algorithm2e - Foreach loop for a string - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332040/foreach-loop-for-a-string)